# Int is not convertible to UIInterfaceOrientationMak for supportedInterfaceOrientations()

Tags: swift, int, uiinterfaceorientation, swift2, xcode7

I have another problem with Xcode 7. I have tried some research but cannot come up with a solution. The error is Int is not convertible to UIInterfaceOrientationMask. The code below:

```
override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    if visibleViewController is KINWebBrowserViewController { return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All.rawValue) }
    return Int(UIInterfaceOrientationMask.Portrait.rawValue)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Swift 3.x**

```
override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return visibleViewController is KINWebBrowserViewController ? .all : .portrait
}
```